# Does Xcode 7.3.1 run on MacOS Sierra (10.12)?

Tags: macos, ios, xcode

i have both x code 7.3.1 and x code 8 installed on OS X 10.11 and i need them both to manage my apps written with swift language.

i have downloaded both from apple website (not from app store) and i still keep the setup files (.dmg & .xip)

will xcode 7.3.1 still work on sierra if i upgrade?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it works. I have macOS Sierra with Xcode 7.3.1.

Tested:

- Simulators
- Debug on device
- Validate/Upload to store
- CocoaPods

Comment: thanks for your answer. is it fully functional after update? i heard that the simulator stops working

Comment: Are cocoapods and Carthage working well?

Comment: @user2602020 See above

Comment: @RobinThuranMalhotra I do not know for Carthage. I installed macOS Sierra GM seed a few days before the release and I was surprised how well it worked. There was one documented issue for homebrew (and easy to fix) and a very specific issue with a custom keyboard layout I use. I do not see any issue on Carthage's Hub about macOS Sierra.

Comment: Hi, with Sierra official released, can Xcode 7 still workable ? As I still need to support iOS 6.

Comment: @neobie Last week we archived an app using 7.3.1. We submitted the 7.3.1 archive using Xcode 8 since there is a bug with the submission now in Xcode 7. The app was released to the app store just fine.

Comment: @neobie, at this point it is not Sierra that will prevent you to release to iOS 6 but when Apple will decide it otherwise.